# WPF App turns into GeneratedApplication

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF Application. In the App.xaml.cs file I had this

```
public static App Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return App.Current as App;
        }
    }
```

I was using MVVM LightToolkit and afterwards I have installed TimePunchWPFLibrary. Tuned out that TimePunch has all the stuff I need from MVVM so I removed MVVM using NuGet. Now for some reason I get the Instance property always as null. Why is that? Well, I have debugged and saw that from now on, the App.Current property is not from App type, but it is XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedApplication. Can anyone tell me why?

P.S. I am not sure that the removing of MVVM Light Toolkit did that, but it happened at the same time.

UPDATE: I have figured it out! The problem was that my x:Class definition was missing in App.xaml. This caused none of the Startup code fro App.xaml.cs to be executed and the application is being Generated kinda like a dummy app.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? I use it in my WPF Applications.

```
    Application.Current
```

**From Microsoft:**
Application is a per-AppDomain singleton type that implements the static Current property to provide shared access to the Application instance for the current AppDomain. This design guarantees that state managed by Application, including shared resources and state, is available from a single, shared location. This property is thread safe and is available from any thread.